# Alternating columns in a datagrid

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight datagrid like this

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="productsDataGrid">
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Desc" Binding="{Binding SmallDesc}"/>
                <data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding SmallPhotoLoc}"></Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>
</data:DataGrid>
```

That will get me this pattern of data like this:
Text    Image
Text    Image
Text    Image
Text    Image

Can anyone please advice on how to get the following pattern:
Text  Image  
Image  Text
Text  Image
Image  Text

Comment: It sounds highly likely that the data grid is not the tool for the job.

Comment: Any suggestions of how else I can do this? Maybe add the image and text to a button and add the button to a stack panel one by one. I say button because I need it to be clickable. In that case I also have to wire up each button to a "click" event. sounds hard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a listbox with a DataTemplateSelector

here is an example

http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/09/28/datatemplateselector-in-silverlight.aspx